# Do all inner products on $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, inner-products

We know that a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold $M$ is a smoothly varying
assignment of an inner product to every tangent space of $M$.

> **Question 1:** Do all inner products on $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent? i.e. one can deform one to another smoothly?

Sorry for the following because I don't know it make sense or not.

> **Question 2:** Does exotic structure on inner product space $\Bbb R^n$ (if exist) induces an exotic structure on Riemannian manifold $M$ with $\Bbb R^n$ as tangent space?

Comment: What do you mean by "exotic structure"?

Comment: Homeo but not diffeo.

Comment: So by "induce", you mean to ask an exotic structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ allows us to construct a homeomorphic, but not diffeomorphic manifold $M'$ for any $n$-manifold $M$?

Comment: Homeomorphism and diffeomorphism and not related to Riemannian metric.

Comment: For question 1. If $g_0$ and $g_1$ are Riemannian metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can deform $g_0$ into $g_1$ using the family of metrics $g_t=(1-t)g_1+tg_0$. But, this not say much about the geometry of this metrics, for instance you can see $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $\mathbb{S}^n/\{p\}$, so you can construct a metric $g_0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. the curvature is constant and equal to 1, that is very diferent from the geometry genereted by the canonical metric, that has constant curvature equal to zero.